# What is the significance of mass excess?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I understood what is meant by [mass excess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_excess) according to the formula $931(m-A)\,\mathrm{MeV}$, but why is it used?
According to the formula, we take difference of mass of atom and atomic mass unit times the mass number, so does it also includes the mass of electrons? I mean, in mass excess. Because, atomic mass also contains the mass of electrons and we only subtract them from the atomic mass unit times the mass number.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can say that it includes the mass of electrons, but an electron weighs approximately 1/10,000 as much as a proton, so electron mass is a small rounding error.
2. Mass excess is useful because it's a nice way of estimating how much "nuclear potential energy" there is in an atom relative to a bunch of free protons.

Comment: Thank You. Please tell me one more thing, that if I put the protons & neutrons aside, then the remaining mass will be due to the electrons only or are there some other things too? No matter, their masses are negligible?

Comment: @UjjwalSharma The mass excess has nothing to do with the electrons. The additional mass is due to the binding energy of the nucleus of the atom. If you look at nuclear decay, a large amount of energy is released and the resulting products have less mass than the original atom before the decay. The rule for the mass/energy conversion ist the famous E=mc2.